# Getting plot figure in mpld3 pip package

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

I'm trying out mpld3 for the first, time, and I want to save a plot as a json file, so I tried the following

```
f=open('my_first_graph.json', 'w+')
plt.hist(population_ages, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
fig = plt.Figure()
fig.show()
plt.title("Populations")
plt.legend()

mpld3.show()
mpld3.save_json(fig, fileobj=f)f= open('my_first_graph.json', 'w+')
plt.hist(population_ages, bins, histtype='bar', rwidth=0.8)
fig = plt.Figure()
fig.show()
plt.title("Populations")
plt.legend()

mpld3.show()
mpld3.save_json(fig, fileobj=f)
```

according to the documentation, the `save_json` method takes in two parameters the file object, and

```
matplotlib Figure instance

The figure to write to file.
```

so I added the file object successfully, and a json file is made, the problem is that It's empty.

How can I make my plot into a figure and pass it into the method as a parameter, to successfully parse it to json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change `fig = plt.Figure()` to `fig = plt.gcf()` in your code.

`plt.Figure` is creating a new empty figure which you're then saving. This is why you're seeing an empty figure.

What you want to do is get a handle on the current figure you created with`plt`, hence you should use `gcf` (get current figure).

Comment: That's great thank you, however my json file is still empty, when i run the method?

Comment: Hm, I'm sorry, I've never used mpld3 before. So I'm just guessing a bit now, but try opening your file as ```f=open('my_first_graph.json', 'wb')```

Comment: thank you for your try, though i get an error, from that, because i can't use the `wb` argument when writing to json

Comment: I figured, the solution, you could just pass in the file name, and it would make it, thank you!

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad you worked this out. Does this solution work regardless of whether you use ```fig = plt.Figure()``` or ```fig = plt.gcf()```?